# How to use JavaScript to realize jQuery queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

jQuery code:

```
target.animate({top:500},{queue: false,duration: 500});
```

How to use  JavaScript to realize the "queue: false" effect?

e.g.  `window.onscroll` event, I just want to be in the end of the event performs some method.

Is this reasonable?:

```
var timer;
window.onscroll = function(){
    console.log('scrolling');
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){console.log('complete');},600);
}
```

Comment: `var timer;window.onscroll = function(){
  console.log('scrolling');
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){console.log('complete');},600);
 } ` I write that reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only wanting to perform actions after the animation is complete, then provide a function as the last argument in the animation.

```
target.animate({top:500}, {queue: false, duration: 500}, function(){
  // Animation complete do something else.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but I wish to use the javascript realized.and I just want to be in the end of the event,not in the end of the animate.